# How do I download a file to the extension folder in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use `chrome.extension.getURL` to load a local file that was downloaded. Since this can only access files in the extensions folder, how do I save files to the extensions folder?

I tried `chrome.downloads.download`, but this saves to the downloads folder by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the file via `XMLHttpRequest`/`$.get`, store it as a string/blob in some local storage like `WebSQL`, `IndexedDB` or `chrome.storage.local`, then add it to a webpage as a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

You can't save the file anywhere except under the downloads directory, see [chrome.downloads API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download):

- `chrome.downloads.download`:

  > Absolute paths, empty paths, and paths containing back-references ".." will cause an error. `onDeterminingFilename` allows suggesting a filename [...]
- `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename`:

  > a path relative to the user's default Downloads directory, possibly containing subdirectories. Absolute paths, empty paths, and paths containing back-references ".." will be ignored.

There are no other APIs to download a file.

Comment: If I go with your approach, would it still be possible to edit the file using the user's file editor?

Comment: No, all the local storage APIs available for extensions use database files like SQLite, for example.

Comment: The thing you want is only possible via writing a separate [native host application](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).